# How to use v-for (Vue.js) to loop a JSON object and split the rendered DOMs into two div containers?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an Axios callback that returns a JSON formatted array that contains 170 key:value pairs. Now I use v-for to render one div container per key:value pair into another div wrapper (so the results are shown as a column).

My estimated output is to have two columns as DOM output, each with 85 key:value pairs.

How can someone make v-for to jump to the second div wrapper once it iterated the first 85 (50%) of the JSON array to endup with two columns created next to each other (assuming html/css structure is fine obv.)?

Thank you very much for your ideas in advance!

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true;

var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '.eurQuotesWrapper',
  data() {
    return {
      rates: []
    }},
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXX&base=EUR")
      .then(response => {
        this.rates = response.data.rates;
      });
  }
});
```

```css
.column {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.headings {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #2E1A6D;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.keyColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}

.valueColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
}

.key {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.value {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

<div class="column">
  <div class="headings">EUR/XXX</div>
  <div class="eurQuotesWrapper">
    <div class="keyColumn">
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates" class="key">[[ key ]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="valueColumn">
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates" class="value">[[ value ]]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="keyColumn">
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates" class="key"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="valueColumn">
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates" class="value"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: splitting the array beforehand is not a solution?
And what about just using css for the effect, do you really need duplicate keyColumn and keyValues?

Comment: I like this idea. How would your approach be to do so? Split it within the axios function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is creating a set of **computed** values that only return the first (or second) half of the object you get from the API. By using computed values, the original response will stay "intact" for future processing.

It's not a DRY solution (but can be modified to be), and I would create a component for the columns - but in this snippet I just used a simpler form of display (`<div v-for=""></div>`)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true;

var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '.eurQuotesWrapper',
  data() {
    return {
      rates: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rates1() {
      const ratesArr = Object.entries(this.rates)
      const ret = ratesArr.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
        if (i <= d.length / 2) a[c[0]] = c[1]
        return a
      }, {})
      console.log('rates1', ret)
      return ret
    },
    rates2() {
      const rateArr = Object.entries(this.rates)
      const ret = rateArr.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
        if (i > d.length / 2) a[c[0]] = c[1]
        return a
      }, {})
      console.log('rates2', ret)
      return ret
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXX&base=EUR")
      .then(response => {
        this.rates = response.data.rates;
      });
  }
});
```

```css
/*.column {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.headings {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #2E1A6D;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.keyColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}

.valueColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
}

.key {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.value {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}*/

.keyColumn {
  float: left;
}

.valueColumn {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="headings">EUR/XXX</div>
    <div class="eurQuotesWrapper">
      <strong>COL1</strong>
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates1">[[key]]: [[value]]</div>
      <hr />
      <strong>COL2</strong>
      <div v-for="(value, key) in rates2">[[key]]: [[value]]</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: this looks nice. Thank you very much. Still learning a lot about Vue.js. Could you maybe explain what you mean by `DRY solution` and the component part? I don't get the action behind this part at all: ```const ret = rateArr.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
        if (i > d.length / 2) a[c[0]] = c[1]
        return a
      },```. Do I have to make any further updates to my code since the console says that `rates1 and rates2 aren't defined on the instance` ?

Comment: Edit: Working fine now. I didn't save my js file properly... jeez

Comment: DRY means “Don’t Repeat Yourself” - it means that you try to code in such a way, that you don’t have sections in your code that repeat multiple times. For that you could rewrite this snippet to handle splitting your data to **n** parts AND display it without two computed values and without a repetition in your template.

Comment: The **reduce** function is “classifying” the result array of the **Object.entries()** - if it’s in the second half of the array, then add it to the ret object, if it’s in the first half then just return what you already have. In **result1** the **reduce()** creates an object from the first half.

Comment: The **component part** is one of the reasons we use modern JS frameworks - you can create components, that can be reused over and over. It’s much broader than I could explain here, sorry - but vuejs.org has multiple sections dedicated to this topic :)

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I have one very last question on the reduce function. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce I cannot find any letter args. What do `(a, c, i, d)` express in your reduce function?

Comment: a - accumulator, c - current, i - index, d - data (the array the function iterates over)

Comment: But it’s there in the docs you linked :) **”The reducer function takes four arguments:”** :) But I think it’s easier to remember “acid” than “acccurridxsrc”

Comment: the d for `source array` killed me :-D

Comment: Yeah, that one is a bit off, but has some sense to it :) - I’m pretty sure you’ll never forget what the reducer function takes as arguments, and in what order :)